# Why OpenSSL in C++ produces different output than command line

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, rsa, sha256

I looked up some code samples for OpenSSL in order to hash some content using SHA256 and sign it using an RSA key - I also need to encode the resulting string to hex. I used this source for reference: https://gist.github.com/irbull/08339ddcd5686f509e9826964b17bb59

This is the higher level method that accepts the message

```
std::string Sign(const std::string& key, const 
std::string& message, bool bPrivate)
{


    RSA* rsa = CreateRSAFromString(key, isPrivate);

    if(!rsa)
    {
        // Print errors here...
        return "";
    }

    unsigned char* outMessage;           
    size_t outMessageLength;

    RSASign(rsa, 
            (unsigned char*) message.c_str(), 
            message.length(), 
            &outMessage, 
            &outMessageLength);


    std::string myString(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(outMessage), outMessageLength);

    // Convert the string to hex
    std::string hexOutMessage = ToHex(myString);
    free(outMessage);
    return hexOutMessage;
}
```

The actual RSA sign method appears pretty straightforward. From my understanding, this should first hash the content using SHA256 then proceeds to encrypting with RSA.

```
bool RSASign(RSA* rsa,
        const unsigned char* msg,
        size_t msgLength,
        unsigned char** outMsg,
        size_t* outMsgLength)
{ 
EVP_MD_CTX* context = EVP_MD_CTX_create();

EVP_PKEY* privateKey = EVP_PKEY_new(); 
EVP_PKEY_assign_RSA(privateKey, rsa);  


if(EVP_DigestSignInit(context, NULL, EVP_sha256(), NULL, privateKey) <= 0)
{
    return false;   // Initialize the digest failed
}

if (EVP_DigestSignUpdate(context, msg, msgLength) <= 0) 
{
    return false;   // Adding the message failed
}

if (EVP_DigestSignFinal(context, NULL, outMsgLength) <= 0)
{
    return false;   // Finalization failed, cannot create signature
}

*outMsg = (unsigned char*)malloc(*outMsgLength);
if(EVP_DigestSignFinal(context, *outMsg, outMsgLength) <= 0)
{
    return false;   // Error creating encoded message
}
EVP_MD_CTX_destroy(context);
// End of context

return true;
}
```

For completeness, this is where the actual creation of the RSA object happens:

```
RSA* CreateRSAFromString(const std::string& key, bool isPrivate)
{
RSA* rsa = NULL;
BIO* keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf((void*)key.c_str(), -1);  

if(!keybio)
{
    return NULL;
}

rsa = isPrivate ? PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(keybio, NULL, NULL, NULL):
                  PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, NULL,NULL, NULL);
return rsa;
}
```

**I want to verify if my process is correct, because when outputting the hex result, I get totally different results between the commandline and C++. Specifically, the equivalent command I am trying to achieve is the following:**

```
dgst -sha256 -sign certifcate.pem -out signed.txt inputFile.json
```

If I can ensure the OpenSSL side of things is correct, then I can probably deduce it is my conversion to hex that introduces the discrepancy. No errors or failures were outputted on the OpenSSL side of things.

Comment: You appear to use a private key in your code, while you're using a certificate (i.e. a public key) with command line. In order to generate a signatutre, you should use the private key as well in your command line.

Comment: Note also that the signature bytes might differ totally even with same data and key. This is depending on the padding applied on the signature (e.g. any random padding scheme like PSS padding).

Comment: @oliv sorry for the misnomer, the certificate.pem is actually a private certificate. Padding seems suspicious, but where in my code should I manage the padding? The methods to create the digest and RSA object don't seem to have arguments that allow me to do that.

Comment: The command line `dgst` command does have a way to change the signature padding scheme using `-sigopt`. It is at least possible with `EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_padding`, but I don't know with the functions you're using

Comment: @oliv interestingly enough, when I input a file without new line characters and unnecessary spacing, my code outputs the same result as the command line. In fact, if I compact my content into a string with no redundant characters, the output is correct.